# Accept dots and whitspaces in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using javascript to check if the username match the criteria.

```
// Check the username
re = /^\w+$/; 
if(!re.test(form.username.value)) { 
    alert("Alert"); 
    form.username.focus();
    return false; 
}
```

In the current state the script accepts letters, numbers and underscores. I also want to accept dots and whitespaces.

Does someone know what I need to change in `/^\w+$/` to accept dots and whitspaces?

Comment: Change it to: `^[\w\s.]+$`

Comment: Please check out the regex docs - https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/259/getting-started-with-regular-expressions#t=201706280523274267623

Answer (score 2):

You can use character classes to include the characters you want. For eg. to include dots and spaces use `/^[. \w]+$/`

Answer (score 1):

Use [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) in regex to include dot and whitespace. Where [`\s`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) can be used for all kind of spaces including newline or simply use whitespace if you don't need newline.

```
re = /^[\w.\s]+$/; 

// in case you just want whitespace then use
re = /^[\w. ]+$/;
```